# Как сохранить хеш-таблицу в файле?

Tags: c#

Использовать простой текстовый файл не получится, т.к. записей может быть до 300.000, а работать с отдельными из них не получится - придётся каждый раз перезаписывать весь файл, что очень долго.
Посоветуйте что можно использовать, для шарпа.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание справочника при помощи хеш-таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1393862/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%b5%d1%88-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ зависит от того, насколько часто будет обновляться hash - таблица.

При небольшом кол-ве обновлений я бы применил следующую схему:

1. делаем "дамп" таблицы в файл
2. начинаем на каждое изменение дописывать в файл (или даже писать в отдельный файл) строку с признаком того, что случилось с таблицей: `insert`, `update` или `delete`

Получается "transaction log для hash table". Внутри файла ничего не меняется, только дописывается в конец.

Недостатки: увеличивается время "загрузки", так как после загрузки основной части таблицы понадобится еще и обработать `transaction log`

Возможны вариации этой схемы, в зависимости от кол-ва обновлений, например, после того, как обновилось 10% всех записей - делать новый "слепок" основной таблицы, чтобы `transaction log` не слишком разрастался.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь разделить таблицу на мелкие части, по 100к - 10к - 1к хешей
Делаешь по 10 папок, в которых папки и.т.д с первыми цифрами инжекса
В этих папках уже будут файлы.
Выглядит вот так (У меня разделено не по десяткам, а по степеням двойки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]